# As a player, what do I need to prepare for Dread?

Tags: new-players, system-introduction, dread

I'm going to be playing in a game of Dread next week.  What if anything do I need to have prepared?  What do I need to bring (pencils, paper, dice, etc)?

Comment: Dread from The Impossible Dream, or Dread: the First Book of Pandemonium from Neoplastic Press?

Comment: Yeah, in other words "the jenga one" or the "shooting demons one"?

Comment: Ummm, the jenga one, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: See [this meta question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/440/do-we-need-two-dread-tags) for a discussion about tagging dread.

Comment: You posted that in the wrong meta group, I fear.

Comment: @Jadasc Fixed now.  Problem with having them all open at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might fill about a character questionnaire at the start of the game, but that's about all the writing you're likely to do, unless you like to take notes.  There is no need for dice or books of any kind.  *Dread* is about as light as games get.  There's pretty much nothing you can do to prepare for it, except practice at home with your Jenga set.

Answer (score 5):

Pencil and paper might be helpful, but you shouldn't need dice. **Dread** uses a tower of balanced wooden blocks as its resolution mechanic; to succeed, you'll need to pull a block from the tower without it collapsing.